# Why does adding count() to my sql query stop it from working?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Why does this return 23 rows (the right amount):

```
select users.user_id, users.fname, users.lname, 
       stars.stars, comments.comment from users 
       LEFT JOIN stars on users.user_id = stars.userid 
       JOIN comments on users.user_id = comments.sender 
       where users.user_id = ? order by comments.time desc;
```

and this return 1 row?:

```
select users.user_id, users.fname, users.lname,
       stars.stars, count(distinct comments.id) as amount,
       comments.comment from users 
       LEFT JOIN stars on users.user_id = stars.userid 
       JOIN comments on users.user_id = comments.sender 
       where users.user_id = ? order by comments.time desc;
```

Cheers.

Comment: it would be best to show some sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to group the main data or do a sub-query for the field.

Comment: @AmitBhargava well if i put group by comments.id at the end it returns the right amount of rows but the count() doesnt so i dont know

Comment: @AndyLobel what is it you are trying to select?

Comment: @Alex hey, I know this is old now but i still cant do it looool, well I can do it with the subquery but not the group by which is what i want. What would i actually tell it to group it by? Cheeeeeers

Comment: Reverse your query. `SELECT [columns], [count] FROM comments JOIN users ON  [condition] WHERE [condition] GROUP BY comments.sender` - this will give your proper count of comments by users